# Вывод значения поля а не в каком поле БД записано flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
@app.route('/signin', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def signin():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    log = request.form.get('login')
    user = db.session.query(users).filter(users.login == login).first()
    print(user)
```

В input ввожу логин, после чего хочу сравнить его с тем логином, что хранится в БД.
Вместо вывода логина выводит <table (номер записи в которой хранится данный логин)>
Мне же нужно просто в переменную user передать логин